# The reaction-role function of my discord.py bot didn't function properly.. Why?

Tags: discord.py

This is the code I got so far but for some reason, it doesn't really work...

```
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel('777877476558110737')
    Text= "React to Verify"
    Moji = await client.send_message(Channel, Text)
    await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='')
    
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('777877476558110737')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
      return
    if reaction.emoji == "":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="12 Year Old")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Channel.send(Text)` not `client.send_message(Channel, Text)` because `send_message` is not a method of `client`, but `send` is a method of `Channel`.
2. Use `Moji.add_reaction("")` not `client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='')` because the `add_reaction` is a method of the `Message` class.
3. Change `user.server.roles` to `user.guild.roles` because `server` is not an attribute of the `Member` class, but `guild` is.
4. Use `user.add_roles(Role)` not `client.add_roles(user, Role)` because `add_roles` is a method of the `Member` class.

Make sure to reference [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). You are calling many methods from the `client` when they are supposed to be called from other classes. Update discord.py to the latest version too.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. Thank you very much!